# OS X El Capitan Split View: How is focus handled?

Tags: macos, mac

Do both windows permanently have focus / are active (good), does focus follow mouse (good), or do you still have to click everything twice (but not too quicky, or it will be interpreted as a double click!) to do stuff just like with two seperate "normal" windows (bad)?

Comment: Focus follows mouse clicks, not just mouse over. If you're a keyboarder, CMD+TAB will move between split and non-split apps

Answer (score 1):

The **X-Windows** focus follows mouse behavior can be activated in limited ways on OS X, and has been this way for some time.   The most useful for command-line driven code developers is for the Terminal app.

The setting that controls the focus follows mouse may be found in

```
~/Library/preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

*Note that the name seems to evolve with versions of the operating system, and for your specific system, it may be* **com.apple.terminal**

To activate focus follows mouse, in a terminal window, enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal FocusFollowsMouse -string YES
```

To deactivate, enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal FocusFollowsMouse -string NO
```

In either case, you'll need to terminate the Terminal program and restart it to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

It is like two separate normal windows, which has never been as bad as you described for the entire history of OS X. Background windows are able to accept and act on clicks as they choose. If you have specific apps that don't accept clicks in the background the way you'd like, that's a bug for that specific app.

Also, play around with holding modifier keys (Command, Option, Control, Shift, etc.) when clicking into a background window. Some apps such as Mail and Finder don't allow you to select an object with a bare click when the window is in the background, but *do* let you select with a Cmd-click.